# Comparing 3 or more Lists of numbers and getting one with highest value

Tags: c#, list

Say I have 3 `List<int>` with the following values:

```
List<int> list1 = {10, 8, 10,  7, 4, 14, 3};
List<int> list2 = {10, 8, 10,  7, 4, 13, 3};
List<int> list3 = {10, 8, 12, 12, 4, 13, 3};
```

I want to compare which of *these 3 lists* have a **higher pair**. `list1` has two `10`, `list2` also has two `10`, whereas `list3` has two `12`.

I want to say that `list3` has the highest pair (since it contains two `12`). Then `list1` is the next highest as even though both `list1` and `list2` has two `10`, the next highest non-pair for `list1` is `14`.

I sorted each list by descending order, but now I'm not sure how to compare the rest of the conditions. Hope you can help me. Thanks!

```
void OrderList(List<int> listToOrder){
   var orderedList = hand.OrderByDescending(x => x);
}
```

Just doing this for list1 arranges it this way:
`{14, 10, 10, 8, 7, 4, 3};`

So now, I'm not sure how to compare highest pairs with the other 2 lists.

Comment: How about a wrapper on which you can apply an IComparer ? Then create a list, throw the three wrapped lists into it and have it ordered ...

Comment: What if two lists both have two or more pairs? Is it then sorted by the next highest pair rather than the next highest non-pair?

Comment: Is "10,10,10" higher than "11,11"?

Comment: Adding to the other questions. What do you expect a method to return: The highest pair in all three lists, the list which contains the highest pair (with or without positions of the pair) or something else?

Comment: @Fildor I haven't used an IComparer before so I'm not sure about the syntax, let me research on that.

Comment: @MatthewWatson that is correct.

Comment: @TimSchmelter "11,11" would still be higher, but I think in my use case... I won't be having 3 of the same values. the max is gonna be 2

Comment: I should've been clearer. I'd like to know which list contains the highest pair. 
@Mushroomator

Comment: Just a rough and dirty first shot: https://dotnetfiddle.net/CyCZ1Q or just with Linq: https://dotnetfiddle.net/sjurcD - probably highly inefficient and only feasable on a small amount of relatively short lists but does the job.

Comment: How would you expect a list with no pairs to be sorted? Or is that not possible? and does the pair have to be exactly 2, or are there different expectations if a list has 3 or more of the same number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Linq you could use something like:

```cs
Using Linq you could use something like:

List<int> list1 = [ 10, 8, 10, 7, 4, 14, 3 ];
List<int> list2 = [ 10, 8, 10, 7, 4, 13, 3 ];
List<int> list3 = [ 10, 8, 12, 12, 4, 13, 3 ];

// Only to have something I can identify which is which.
Dictionary<string, List<int>> dictionary = new()
{
    [nameof(list1)] = list1,
    [nameof(list2)] = list2,
    [nameof(list3)] = list3
};


// Discard non-paired values 12, 12 will leave only 12.

var listWithHighestPair = "none";
var maxPairValue = 0;

foreach (var item in dictionary)
{
    var groupedValues = item.Value.GroupBy(value => value);

    // Get only the numbers that have a duplicate
    var filteredValues = groupedValues
        .Where(group => group.Count() == 2)
        .Select(group => group.Key);

    // Max pair in the list
    var currentMaxPairValue = filteredValues.Max();

    // Update the highest if found any
    if (currentMaxPairValue > maxPairValue)
    {
        maxPairValue = currentMaxPairValue;
        listWithHighestPair = item.Key;
    }
    
}

Console.WriteLine($"The list with the highest value is {listWithHighestPair} with pair: {maxPairValue}");
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this seems to be exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

We can use *Linq* to get `list` highest pair or `int.MinValue` if `list` doesn't have any pair:

```
private static int HighestPair(IEnumerable<int> list) => list
  .GroupBy(item => item)              // We group equal items 
  .Where(group => group.Count() >= 2) // We want pairs (group of size 2 or more) 
  .Select(group => group.Key)          
  .DefaultIfEmpty(int.MinValue)       // int.MinValue if we don't have pairs
  .Max();
```

Then you can organize lists into a collection, say, an array and query this collection:

```
var lists = new[] {
  list1, list2, list3 // Add all your lists here
};

// List with highest pair
var result = lists.MaxBy(list => HighestPair(list));

// Highest pair, if we want it
// var topPair = lists.Max(list => HighestPair(list));
```

Let's have a look:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result));
```

Output:

```
10, 8, 12, 12, 4, 13, 3
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Np3cG8)

Finally, if you want to *sort* lists while comparing them by

- Highest pair
- In case of tie, highest item

```
var ordered = lists
   .OrderByDescending(list => HighestPair(list))
   .ThenByDescending(list => list.Max())
   .ToList();
```